# Annotating score with lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I'm using lilypond (2.12.3-1, on mac) and latex to write a short summary on music theory. 
Therefore I need to annotate a simple scale like in this example picture (I don't need the red squares):

[image: example annotated scale]

The only thing I found were the analysis brackets (http://lsr.dsi.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=426), but they didn't work; I'm getting compile errors.

So I would be very happy to get some working solutions, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Voice
    \consists "Horizontal_bracket_engraver"
  }
}

\version "2.12.3" \relative c' {

  c1 \startGroup 
  d1 _\markup { \left-align { "1. Tetrachord" } } 
     \once \override HorizontalBracket #'direction = #UP
  e1 \startGroup ^\markup { \left-align { "HS" } } 
  f1 \stopGroup \stopGroup

  g1 \startGroup 
  a1 _\markup { \left-align { "2. Tetrachord" } } 
     \once \override HorizontalBracket #'direction = #UP
  b1 \startGroup ^\markup { \left-align { "HS" } } 
  c1 \stopGroup \stopGroup

}
```

produces:

[image]

HTH

Comment: @Masala, you're welcome. You're welcome to post Lilypond questions here of course, but, in case you're not aware of it, there's also a [Tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) sister site. I'd imagine there to be more Lilypond users then there are over here. Best of luck!

Comment: This works for generic editorial markup; however, is there a way to input the standard "half-step" inverted V and "whole-step" bracket?

Comment: @JohnPeyton it's been a while, but I remember not being able to get the inverted V to work. I recommend asking the question on the [Tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) sister. Good luck!